# Can Lego Mindstorms EV3 be run on Intel Atom 1.33 GHz CPU?

Tags: mindstorms

The specifications at [Lego official site here](https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/download-software) say that Dual Core 2.0GHz CPU or better is needed. Still, maybe quad core with 1.8 GHz (like [Prestiogio Multipad Visconte](https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/94412f99)'s Intel Atom quad core) would work smoothly enough?

Have anyone tried to run Lego Mindstorms EV3 on such kind of CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, yes but performance will be slow because you have a very slow CPU. You can increase performance of the software by disabling visual effects in Windows and by closing background apps.